# Get the more accurate user location android

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm building an app that track user movement. I found on the net and I'm still  blocked about how to get a reliable user location.

For that purpose, I started by use the GPS_PROVIDER to get user location every minutes. But that drains a lot of battery.
Now I'm using NETWORK_PROVIDER which have better yield on battery, but as per my understanding, is not really accurate.

So firstly, I want to know to deal between usage of those providers to have good yield regarding battery consumption and user location accuracy.

Secondly, I read there ([Significant Motion](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#significant_motion))  that:

> At the high level, the significant motion detector is used to reduce the power consumption of location determination. When the localization algorithms detect that the device is static, they can switch to a low power mode, where they rely on significant motion to wake the device up when the user is changing location.

Does it mean that this sensor is already used by GPS_NETWORK or that applications have to implement the described behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided (significant motion) relates to accelerometer, which you shouldn't be conncerned much when implementing location tracking.

What you probably need is `Fused Location Provider API` from Google Play Services, read more here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html. It automatically merges data from GPS and Network providers, also synchronising access to location information between applications. It gives you fairly simple configuration options (how accurate location do you want? How often would you like to get updates?), and Play Services framework takes care of providing you with location in very efficient manner.

Since this is pretty extensive topic, I'll just refer to you documentation: the link above specifically [this section](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). You should find plenty of tutorials too.